# Rails5/Devise/Omniauth (Multiple Providers)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, authentication, twitter, facebook

I spent the better part of the last two days getting this to work, but it finally is working, but it feels extremely redundant.

I am following a `belongs_to` method for a table called 'authorizations' - I want a user to be able to sign up via Email, or any Omniauth channel I implement that has an Email(I'll give it a Devise password), and freely link/unlink authorized apps.

**Auth Controller**

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :steam

  def index
    @authentications = current_user.authentications.all
  end
  # <%= link_to 'Authentications', authentications_path %>
  def home
  end

  def twitter
     omni = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
     authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omni['provider'], omni['uid'])

     if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Logged in Successfully"
      sign_in_and_redirect User.find(authentication.user_id)
     elsif current_user
      token = omni['credentials'].token
      token_secret = omni['credentials'].secret

      current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omni['provider'], 
                                          :uid => omni['uid'], 
                                          :token => token, 
                                          :token_secret => token_secret)
      flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
      sign_in_and_redirect current_user
     else
      user = User.new
      user.apply_omniauth(omni)

      if user.save
         flash[:notice] = "Logged in."
         sign_in_and_redirect User.find(user.id)             
      else
         session[:omniauth] = omni.except('extra')
         redirect_to new_user_registration_path
      end
     end 
   end

   def destroy
     @authentication = Authentication.find(params[:id])
     @authentication.destroy
     redirect_to authentications_url, :notice => "Successfully destroyed authentication."
   end


   def facebook
     omni = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
     authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omni['provider'], omni['uid'])

     if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Logged in Successfully"
      sign_in_and_redirect User.find(authentication.user_id)
     elsif current_user
      token = omni['credentials'].token
      token_secret = ""

      current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omni['provider'], 
                                           :uid => omni['uid'], 
                                           :token => token, 
                                           :token_secret => token_secret)

      flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
      sign_in_and_redirect current_user
     else
      user = User.new
      user.email = omni['extra']['raw_info'].email 

      user.apply_omniauth(omni)

      if user.save
         flash[:notice] = "Logged in."
         sign_in_and_redirect User.find(user.id)             
      else
         session[:omniauth] = omni.except('extra')
         redirect_to new_user_registration_path
      end
     end
   end

    def steam
        omni = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omni['provider'], omni['uid'])

        if authentication
            flash[:notice] = "Logged in Successfully"
            sign_in_and_redirect User.find(authentication.user_id)
        elsif current_user
        token = omni['extra']['raw_info'].steamid
        # render :text => request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.to_hash.inspect

        puts token
        token_secret = ""

            current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omni['provider'], 
                                                 :uid => omni['uid'], 
                                                 :token => token, 
                                                 :token_secret => token_secret)
            flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
            sign_in_and_redirect current_user
        else
            user = User.new
            user.apply_omniauth(omni)
        end

        if user.save
            flash[:notice] = "Logged in."
            sign_in_and_redirect User.find(user.id)             
        else
            session[:omniauth] = omni.except('extra')
            redirect_to new_user_registration_path
        end
    end




end
```

This part is extremely redundant, esp when I made more modifications last night to finally get steam to even work.

The function it uses within the `user model`

**User.rb**

```
  def apply_omniauth(omni)
    authentications.build(:provider => omni['provider'], 
                          :uid => omni['uid'],
                          :token => omni['credentials'].token, 
                          :token_secret => omni['credentials'].secret)
  end


  def password_required?
    (authentications.empty? || !password.blank?) && super #&& provider.blank?
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      end
  end
```

I'm populating fake data for Steam, just as I am for Twitter.

I finally do have the joins working on every form, though the final 'else' (Not signed up, trying to freshly join) isn't working as I'd expect I'm trying to see about minimizing redundancies before I bug test.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option for removing redundancy: replace the the provider specific `def`s with a single one like the following:

```
def authlenticate
    # I misspelled authlenticate above on purpose
    # Steam requires a different handling of the authenticity token 
    omni = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omni['provider'], omni['uid'])

    if authentication
        flash[:notice] = "Logged in Successfully"
        sign_in_and_redirect User.find(authentication.user_id)
    elsif current_user
        token = omni['credentials'].token || omni['extra']['raw_info'].steamid
    # if steam produces a value for omni['credentials'].token then the above line will fail for steam
        token_secret = omni['credentials'].secret || ""
    # if omni['credentials'].secret is not provided (e.g. FB) then set it to ""
        current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omni['provider'], 
                                      :uid => omni['uid'], 
                                      :token => token, 
                                      :token_secret => token_secret)
        flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
        sign_in_and_redirect current_user
    else
        user = User.new
        user.apply_omniauth(omni)

        if user.save
         flash[:notice] = "Logged in."
         sign_in_and_redirect User.find(user.id)             
        else
         session[:omniauth] = omni.except('extra')
         redirect_to new_user_registration_path
        end
    end 
end
```